# Error - firestore is not defined (Only after "then")

Tags: angular, typescript, google-cloud-firestore

I have a problem : When I want to create fake users in my database, everything work like a charm until I start the loop 'for'.

At this point, I have this error :

> Error adding document:  TypeError: Cannot read property 'firestore' of
>   undefined

I've try multiple things but nothing work ... Do you have an idea ?

Thank you all !

```
create_NewUser(data:any){
        this.firestore.collection('Users-test').add({
          name:data.name,
          town:data.town,
          gender:data.gender,
          email:data.email,
          picture:data.picture,
          birthdate:data.birthdate
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
          // console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          let nbInterest:any = data.interests.length;
          // let nbAvailaibilities:any = data.interests.length;
          for (let index = 0; index < nbInterest; index++) {
            this.firestore.collection('Users-test').doc("/" + docRef.id + "/interests/" + index).add({
              interest:data.interests[index]
            }) 
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this:

In your create_NewUser:

```
const that = this;
```

Inside for loop use

```
that.firestore
.collection('Users-test').doc("/" + docRef.id + "/interests/" + index).add({
......
});
```

This is because this in not in the scope of then and is not referable.

Complete:

```
create_NewUser(data:any){
        const that = this;
        this.firestore.collection('Users-test').add({
          name:data.name,
          town:data.town,
          gender:data.gender,
          email:data.email,
          picture:data.picture,
          birthdate:data.birthdate
        })
        .then(function(docRef) {
          // console.log("Document written with ID: ", docRef.id);
          let nbInterest:any = data.interests.length;
          // let nbAvailaibilities:any = data.interests.length;
          for (let index = 0; index < nbInterest; index++) {
            that.firestore.collection('Users-test').doc("/" + docRef.id + "/interests/" + index).add({
              interest:data.interests[index]
            }) 
          }
        })
        .catch(function(error) {
            console.error("Error adding document: ", error);
        });
      }
```

Binding is also a way suggested by scorpioo590

Comment: Good Answer ! Thank you !

Answer (score 2):

Taken from [here](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/when-and-why-you-should-use-es6-arrow-functions-and-when-you-shouldnt-3d851d7f0b26/):

> In classic function expressions, the this keyword is bound to different values based on the context in which it is called. With arrow functions however, this is lexically bound. It means that it usesthis from the code that contains the arrow function.

This means: in the function that you pass as an argument to `then` `this` is not defined.

#### Arrow function

You can use an arrow-function that binds to the "surrounding" `this`.

```
.then((docRef) => {
    // process this here
})
```

#### Bind `this` to the function

You can explicitly bind an object to a function that is treated as `this` within the function

```
.then(function(docRef) {
     // process this here
}.bind(this))
```